# When you cast invisibility on your turn, and walk away from 2 enemies, do they get an attack of opportunity?

Tags: dnd-5e, opportunity-attack, invisibility, line-of-sight

When a PC is in melee with a creature, casts the basic invisibility spell, and leaves melee, does an NPC get an attack of opportunity?

Answer (score 42):

**No, they don't get opportunity attacks.**

From PHB, page 195:

> You can make an opportunity attack when a hostile creature **that you can see** moves out of your reach.

Comment: Beat me to the punch. +1