# If a character casts Fog Cloud around themselves before moving away from an enemy, do they provoke an opportunity attack?

Tags: dnd-5e, opportunity-attack, vision-and-light

Our party was forced to brawl against a group of orcs in order to gain their respect to speak with their chieftain (long story, we had very good reason for doing this). It then became a battle royale.

Our wizard was at low health and next to our paladin, and had the idea to cast *fog cloud* to capture himself and the paladin within it so he could leave combat. He cast the spell, and then came down to the debate of whether the paladin would get an opportunity attack even though she was blinded.

The wizard *was* in threat range, but does an effect that causes an area to become heavily obscured cause the Paladin to lose threat range and the wizard be able to successfully flee to another area of the ring?

Or does the paladin still have threat range and attack the wizard, even with *fog cloud* covering both of them?

I looked over the rules for 15 minutes after this situation, but nothing came up.  It was ruled in-game that it was fine to make an opportunity attack with disadvantage, but that just doesn't feel right. She might have heard the wizard stepping away, but the *fog cloud* was already in place. By the D&D rules, would the paladin have been able to make the opportunity attack or not?

Comment: Related: [When you cast invisibility on your turn, and walk away from 2 enemies, do they get an attack of opportunity?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/102594/when-you-cast-invisibility-on-your-turn-and-walk-away-from-2-enemies-do-they-g), [Can a character with the Polearm Master feat make an opportunity attack against an invisible creature that enters their reach?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/149983/can-a-character-with-the-polearm-master-feat-make-an-opportunity-attack-against)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

## No Opportunity Attack

[Fog Cloud](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/fog-cloud) creates a:

> sphere [that] spreads around corners, and its area is heavily obscured

An area that is [Heavily Obscured](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/adventuring#VisionandLight) makes (emphasis mine):

> A creature effectively suffers from the **blinded** condition when trying to see something in that area.

The [Blinded](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/appendix-a-conditions#Blinded) condition stipulates:

> A blinded creature can't see

And finally, [Opportunity Attacks](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/combat#OpportunityAttacks) occur (emphasis mine):

> when a hostile creature that **you can see** moves out of your reach

In the case of Fog Cloud with Heavy Obscurement, unless the creature has tremor sense or something else that enables them to 'see' you, you would be able to move away without triggering an Opportunity Attack.