# Can I cast Darkness in my mouth so I can turn it on/off each round without having to use an action?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, actions, targeting

I am playing a 5e game, and I had the idea of casting *darkness* in my mouth, or on a small rock that I then place in my mouth.

At the start of each of my turns, I close my mouth. This obscures the darkness, giving my character full visual sight during their turn. Then, at the end of my turn, I open my mouth, obscuring the character in complete darkness.

This presumes a character could open and close their mouth as free actions during their turn. And since they can speak freely, under normal circumstances, I don't see why this wouldn't be allowed. Other than it feels spell-breaking, in that it becomes OP in a way probably unintended.

The idea of casting the spell on the rock is so that you could also spit the rock out on the ground and keep moving. Or spit the rock into your hand and throw it in a cardinal direction.

I think it would also be fun if during this time when my mouth is closed to obscure the *darkness*, I'm not able to speak more than a mumble IRL to the other players.

I'm going to bring this up with my DM before attempting it, but I wanted to get some thoughts on the concept first.

Is this possible within the rules? Am I missing anything obvious?

Comment: @sevenbrokenbricks While it's a similar mechanical issue, the title of that question should make it clear that it was a very different problem.

Comment: Yeah, that's not even close to being a dup

Comment: Related: [Can I retrieve and then stow away an item every turn without using up my Action?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/130799/can-i-retrieve-and-then-stow-away-an-item-every-turn-without-using-up-my-action)

Comment: Is it a duplicate, isn't it? https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/110092/

Comment: @enkryptor just because the "*darkness* on something in my mouth" issue comes up in both doesn't necessarily mean the questions are duplicates. In the case you like the question is explicitly about handling player argument, where the *darkness*-imbued object is simply the example. In this case the question is actually *about* a mouth-held *dark* object--they're not the same question by a long shot. See also https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10844/311001

Comment: @nitsua60 although, the main point of the answer is also the simultaneous combat

Comment: "Other than it feels spell-breaking, in that it becomes OP in a way probably unintended." - can you please describe how exactly this is OP? I really don't think this "exploit", when used according to the mechanical rules (i.e. being a rogue and using your bonus action to interact with the object twice, or simply using a bonus action, w/e) would be broken in any way.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

## This Would Not Work

...but not because of the way the Darkness spell works.

This wouldn't work because of an issue with the way combat happens. Combat is taken in turns, but it doesn't *actually* happen in turns. Mechanically, only because of how hard it is to actually do otherwise, combat is consecutive, but in actuality, combat is **simultaneous**.

Everyone is supposed to be fighting and defending at the same time, just your reaction times are different. Which means that open and closing your mouth during your turn won't actually do anything, since everyone else is attacking and defending during the same period of time as well. All that would happen is that there would be a strobe effect in the middle of you trying to kill each other.

Comment: This is the type of answer I was looking for. Thank you. Going to mull this over for a bit.

Comment: The simultaneity of combat is in practice impossible to consistently apply. Does the orc warlord on initiative count 2 who suffered massive damage from a rogue, and died, still get to make an attack of opportunity on the paladin on initiative count 3 who decides to move away from the dead foe?

Comment: Could an example be added of what *does* happen when the rogue tries anyway the tactic in the question? The best I can come up with—according to this answer—is this: "At the beginning of your turn, you close your mouth, ending the darkness, and stab at the orc, but you realize too late that on the orc's turn the orc was in the dark, so now you still can't see the orc. Then, at the turn's end, you reopen your mouth, and darkness fills the area once more." And that narrative seems to me *very* strange.

Comment: Oooo @SevenSidedDie, I don't want to drag the comments out too much but that sounds like an interesting thought exercise! Couldn't we say in that case that although we don't know exactly when it happens we know that the Orc, Rogue and Paladin are locked in close combat, and some point the Orc dies, killed by the Rouge, and the Paladin then uses this opportunity to move on. So although we don't know _absolute_ times we can have a rough idea of _relative_ times? Hence, the Darkness trick here doesn't work as it requires knowing exactly when things are happening?

Comment: sorry, but this just isn't true at all! not even a little bit! this response says it plainly: "mechanically, combat is consecutive". consider for a second the same scenario but not in a context where we are tempted to grasp for a reason to disallow this gimmick of being able to toggle darkness. what if OP already had darkness on from earlier, moves, loses concentration on their own turn due to an AOO, and then reactivates it. would you say "nope sorry, turns are simultaneous so your spell doesn't do anything to affect the next guy's turn"? of course not! turns are consecutive, and that's that.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie We don't have to apply it consistently. Turns are an abstraction. This is a case where the abstraction breaks down and needs a reality check.

Comment: @K.M turns are an imperfect abstraction. As such, they are prone to being broken. While that may happen by chance, it shouldn't be allowed on purpose. Yes, that's inconsistent, but it still makes sense.

Comment: As mentioned in my answer to another question (https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/134825/43856), I don't think this kind of ruling is in spirit of the game in any way, has no RAW or RAI back up and even if you want to treat the combat as chaotic ("simultaneous" is never mentioned in the corebooks as far as I am aware), there are many ways to justify these interactions that actually go by the actual rules. Sorry, but this doesn't seem a good answer for RPG.se standards unless you can provide actual back up for your statements.

Comment: @HellSaint: I would argue about the point of view of Rule 0. Any exploit, no matter whether it is remotely possibly justifiable by a certain reading of the rules, should be nipped in the bud by the DM. I take this answer in the spirit of Rule 0: the rules of D&D are there to model the reality of the fantasy world in a way that is conducive to playing, they do not *define* reality, only *describe* it. One could argue that in this case the rules prevent the exploit, but that's a letting the lawyery player put its foot in the door for the next exploit attempt.

Comment: @MatthieuM. If you are going to use Rule 0 argument, there is nothing anyone can do. The DM can rule whatever he wants with or without reasons. About the exploit point, I don't even see an exploit here. Probably people are misunderstanding how darkness works. Also that's essentially an answer to the question I linked, so you can try to give it there.

Comment: @DonQuiKong That's not related to my point. This answer is wrong, as it relies on the incorrect premise that turns in DnD 5e are simultaneous. I hope my counterexample is able to illustrate that - I think anyone would agree that the spell continues. I agree that we want to disallow breaking the game on purpose but that's not pertinent to the correctness of this answer, is it? If there's no RAW or RAI way to fix this particular exploit (and, in my opinion, RAI on "a rock in my mouth" is unclear), then we simply have to reach for a houserule. And that's fine! But the answer is still incorrect.

Comment: Wouldn't another problem with this line of reasoning, in addition to those already mentioned in the comments, be horribly nerfing the Blink spell?

Answer (score 19):

## Inside your mouth is not a legal target

Only points in space or objects are legal targets for *darkness* — since the inside of your mouth is part of you (a creature), you can’t cast it there.

### Your PC’s mouth is also likely not opaque

You could fix the targeting by casting it on a marble or similar that you could place in your mouth after the casting, but then you have the problem that your mouth is unlikely to count as “opaque” by any of its senses (except the irrelevant one that describes an object’s shininess):

> **[opaque](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/opaque)**, adjective
>
> 1. not transparent or translucent; impenetrable to light; not allowing light to pass through.
> 2. not transmitting radiation, sound, heat, etc.
> 3. not shining or bright; dark; dull.

The combined skin and lining of the human mouth is translucent, in that it permits light (but not distinct images) to pass through. Elven, gnomish, and etc. mouths are not known to be different from human mouths in this regard either.

As a way to get a “free” (and therefore infinitely-usable per turn) toggle control on *darkness*, it’s *highly* questionable.

A dragonborn's scales *might* make their mouth opaque — check with your DM about this, but mind that contrary to appearances, scales are often translucent like skin, too. Even then, also mind that you'll likely still have to use the action economy as below, anyway.

### How to toggle *darkness* for cheap, but not free

You have one item interaction per turn that won’t cost an action. Any scheme for toggling *darkness* will use that, even if it's in a somehow-opaque mouth, because of the aforementioned game-breakage.

So, to toggle *darkness* in a way that any PC race can use and keeps the game intact, just secure your marble to the inside of a small light-tight box tied to your belt; use your free item interaction to flip it open or closed.

That’s as big as this exploit really gets, and it’s not that powerful.

Comment: You think mouths are transparent or translucent?

Comment: @DavidRice Try taking a flashlight and holding it up to your cheek. I'd say your mouth is definitely translucent.

Comment: @DavidRice Translucent. Although now that you mention it, a dragonborn's scales may change that, so I've noted that.

Comment: You think inside your mouth is not a point in space? :D Isn't _everywhere_ a point in space? (New to DnD so if there is a specific distinction here I don't know of it, my question is half joking, half serious!)

Comment: @RyanfaeScotland It is, but then the *darkness* effect won’t move with you and stay centred inside your mouth unless you stay very still, which isn’t really doable in combat.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie It is doable if one is paralyzed, restrained, or petrified during combat. :) (I realize that isn't what the querent is looking to do)

Comment: @KorvinStarmast - And, as an extra bonus, if you're petrified, then your mouth will become opaque, as well!

Comment: You could definitely hold a tongue ring in your hand and then insert it in your tongue once the spell had been cast on it.

Comment: @intuited See last section.

Answer (score 16):

## This would violate the Object Interaction Rules

In 5th Edition D&D, you're granted 1 free object interaction per turn, limited to only simple interactions. Opening your mouth probably counts (to make the object visible) and closing it probably also counts (to make it obscured) but doing both in the same turn would require you to use the *Use an Object* Action.

It might seem strange, but mechanically, it's not requiring (substantially) more effort than lifting said rock out of your pocket + putting it back.

## A *Thief* archetype Rogue might have an easier time of it

Thief Archetype Rogues gain the *Fast Hands* feature at level 3, permitting them to perform the *Use an Object* Action as a Bonus Action instead. So theoretically, as a Thief Rogue (multiclassed with whatever class gives you Spellcasting abilities), you could

- Close your mouth (Free Object Interaction)
- Cast a Spell or make an Attack (Action)
- Open your mouth (Bonus Action)

You could also do something less disgusting, like putting the rock inside a latched box that you then open + close using this sequence.

## Some DMs are particular about the Simultaneity of Combat

Because the separation of combat into distinct "turns" is meant to be an abstraction of real-time combat, some DMs interpret this as meaning that it's not possible to meaningfully "strobe" an effect like this without some delayed interaction (i.e. a Reaction used on someone else's turn). **The degree to which this is RAW is hotly contested**, but this is a common interpretation of the rules.

So as a result, some DMs may rule that this is what *actually* happens:

- You close your mouth (Free Object Interaction)

  - The *Darkness* effect may or may not vanish, depending on what happens before your turn ends
- You make an attack or cast a spell. If you open your mouth later in this turn, the attack is made with Disadvantage, or the spell must not require visibility of the target
- *If you open your mouth* the Darkness effect doesn't vanish.
- *If you instead* choose not to open your mouth, the *Darkness* effect does vanish (becomes obscured by your mouth) at the time you close your mouth (???)

Again: I am not certain that is a RAW ruling. I'm just informing you that that is a ruling many DMs make.

## Human[oid] biology is disgusting

Strictly RAW, the *Darkness* effect spreads around corners, and so long as there is an unbroken path to all points within its radius, the *Darkness* spreads to that point. So some DMs may rule that the inside of your mouth (which is connected to your nostrils, even your ears to a degree, through your windpipe...) does not adequately obscure the *Darkness* effect. This may vary depending on the creature's race, but 5e doesn't describe in precise detail how the anatomy of other Humanoid races vary from the anatomy of humans.

Comment: I love how Fast Hands lets you move your mouth faster. Also, if you can speak a short sentence for free, that tends to involve a lot of mouth opening and closing. Not sure I'd agree with you for that reason.

Comment: @MarkTO The Object Interaction rules have to apply to mouth movements [when they interact with objects] as well, or it leads to lots of weird exploits. Yes, it is very strange to rule that a person can't open AND close their mouth in less than 6 seconds unless they're a Thief.

Comment: "Some DMs are particular about the Simultaneity of Combat" I'd say it's more "Some DM's take issue with trying to use game mechanics to break the laws of physics/continuity". It's kinda the DM's job to shut down anything that requires the character performing the action to understand the meta rules that govern their universe (game).

Comment: Strictly speaking, the "peasant rail-gun" is still a valid "exploit" of 5ed.

Comment: @Tezra I respect that; but also, turning a light source (or Darkness, which is basically just "negative light") on and then off doesn't strike me as the sort of act that would "break the laws of physics/continuity" moreso than the mere existence of Magic does. And a character trying to hide in darkness, but moving that darkness when they move to attack is a pretty plausible sequence of events, irrespective of whether the rules actually permit that sort of action, or what that sequence of events has to be abstracted as within the mechanical confines of D&D rules.

Comment: @Xirema allow me to replace "continuity" with "suspension of disbelief". Since common sense says there is no way to manipulate the darkness so that you see everything you are doing, and the enemy can't do anything to you during that moment; it's sorta the DM's job to shut it down (because it requires meta-knowledge of how the rules work) I just mean to say "If you exploit the rules to do something that makes no logical sense narrativly, be prepared for the DM to shut it down".

Comment: @Tezra "I cover up the darkness so I can see, make my attack, then uncover it" is a pretty common sense strategy that doesn't require metagaming knowledge to execute; the only metagaming is working out what sequence of actions/bonus actions are required to satisfy the constraints of the 5e combat engine. There's a lot more metagaming involved in explaining why it doesn't work (or what you totally need to make it work) than in explaining why a character would think it is a good idea.

Comment: @Xirema The reason this wouldn't work in reality, is that as soon as the character opens their mouth, their opponent would be able to see them and attack them effectively. Chances are, in this situation, their opponent would wait for the character to open their mouth, holding their attack to strike. You could rule that the character has to ready an action now, but since everything happens in real time, it would make sense that this effect wouldn't be as powerful as being in continual darkness from the spell. This tactic is still useful - but more as an escape tactic than a combat one.

Comment: @Joshu'sMu That also requires their opponent to Ready an Action though: "as soon as they cover up the *Darkness*, I attack them".

Comment: @Xirema I suppose, but you're really getting into munchkin territory; this isn't really providing much of a tangible benefit (now everyone has to ready actions to avoid penalties from darkness) and it is complicating combat significantly. I think any sensible DM would simply rule that every combatant can time their turns (which don't *actually* happen sequentially, but are instead simultaneous) to allow them to act when the lights are on. I would rule that this has no effect if my players tried to use it this way, otherwise every combat would turn into a readied action-fest.

Comment: @Joshu'sMu The bigger issue is that [Darkness doesn't (usually) confer Disadvantage or Advantage when used](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/99902/42386), meaning readying an action in this situation doesn't remove any penalties—because the penalty wasn't affecting them in the first place.

Comment: "_Human[oid] biology is disgusting_... (which is connected to your nostrils, even your ears to a degree, through your windpipe...)" - Oh come on, it's **_much_** more disgusting than that! Think about what happens when you eat something... it travels through a tube to your stomach where the walls absorb the good stuff and the remains travel through another tube to be expelled. If we are going to use connected biology as a reason for it not working I think 'You close your mouth but the Darkness continues to leak out of your anus.' is much more effective.

Answer (score 5):

While opening and closing your mouth might be free, timing it such that you don't hinder your allies and blind your enemies in the exact moment they take aim looks complicated enough that you should not be able to do it freely. Also, this may not prevent the enemies from delaying the attack until you close the mouth again, effectively having them attack first as soon as vision is restored (thus not having any practical effect in the attack sequence)

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it would work, at least for most races. Per the Darkness spell:

> Completely covering the source of the darkness with an opaque object, such as a bowl or a helm, blocks the darkness.

Oral cavities are not opaque (try putting a flashlight in your mouth), and I'd extend that to all normal player races. I could see this working with, say, a stone golem.

Comment: By extension, then, putting a rock on which *darkness* has been cast into one's mouth means that the magical darkness continues emanating from the rock through its (presumably) human container, making it at least *difficult* for foes to access the source of the darkness. Correct?

Comment: Maybe this should be a separate question, but does the mouth count as an object?

Comment: @mech, That's a good point, there could definitely be a conversation about what is and an isn't opaque. I would say that if you can't see through it, it's not opaque. And as a practical test, could anyone from the outside tell how dark it is in another persons mouth? And if they can't differentiate then it's opaque to their visual perception.

A way around also might be to craft something opaque that can be held in the mouth. Or just keep some ink on hand to swish around?

Comment: @Ling, Maybe the person is the object and their mouth just a part of the object?

Comment: If you want to be super technical, the spell does read: "The darkness spreads around corners." It could be argued that the darkness will wrap around into your sinus passages and out your nose.  Now you've got to plug your nose to do it.  Not that holding your breath during strenuous activity is remotely challenging in 5e.

Comment: @BaconBits There's a joke to be made on that point regarding digestive tracts...

Comment: @Ling Only on a corpse, and even then the object is the corpse.

Comment: @Bryan Casler A person is a creature, not an object.

Comment: now I can't stop imagining people eating darkness pebbles and emanating darkness from their orifices

Comment: @pqnet Which, as I am sure you will recall, is the origin of the legend of Sir Darkfart, the Unfortunate ...